# Image Library with zoom and 2D rotation

Tags: jquery, html, rotation, zooming, image-gallery

I am searching for an image gallery plugin to add it to my asp.net project that takes a list of images and display it with elow features:

- zoom in and out
- next and back buttons
- rotation left and right (Not 3D)
- responsive

In my searches I couldn't find one that gathers all above features, I found one interesting [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/jQuery-Plugin-for-Image-Zoom-Rotation-Plugin-iviewer.html) but in this template I cannot display multiple images with next and back buttons. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the roundrr plugin by Addy Osmani. Although this was written longtime back and might not be responsive, but this can be your starting point and you can add css classes for responsive design.

https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-roundrr

Hope it helps!